# Flatten nested for loops with C++20 ranges

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Sometimes I need to "double for loop" and since I do nothing in outer for loop for first loop variable beside passing it to inner for loop I wonder if it can be done elegantly with C++20 ranges.

Example of nested for loops I would like to "flatten".

```
struct Person{
    std::string name = "Bjarne";
};

std::vector persons{Person{}, Person{}};

int main() {
    for (const auto& person: persons) {
        for (const auto& ch: person.name) {
            std::cout << ch << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Best what I can think of [is](https://godbolt.org/z/9bxxooMPK):

```
std::ranges::for_each(persons | std::views::transform(&Person::name) | std::views::join, [](const char& ch){
    std::cout << ch << std::endl;
});
```

but I wonder if there is a simpler way.

Comment: I'm not sure it's simpler, but it's a little shorter: `for(char ch : persons | std::views::transform(&Person::name) | std::views::join) std::cout << ch << '\n';`

Comment: BTW, `std::cout` can directly output `std::string` :)

Comment: @Jarod42 I presume you are just joking(not sure since :) not ;) ) but it is just an example, in reality it could be a vector < list < SomeClass > >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, what you propose is correct. Except it can still be a range-based for statement, you don't have to switch to an algorithm:

```cpp
for (const auto& ch : persons
                    | std::views::transform(&Person::name)
                    | std::views::join)
{
    // ... 
}
```

Most languages use the name `map` instead of `transform`, and `flatten` instead of `join` (indeed your question title asks about flattening). And then it's common to put these two together with a new algorithm called `flat_map` which does both of these things together.

We can do that too:

```cpp
inline constexpr auto flat_map = [](auto f){
    return std::views::transform(f) | std::views::join;
};

for (const auto& ch : persons | flat_map(&Person::name))
{
    // ... 
}
```

Although in C++ I suppose this would be called `transform_join`? Meh. `flat_map` all the way.

---

Pro-tip: [use `fmt::print`](https://godbolt.org/z/4aPzvs3K9) to print ranges, less to write and it already comes out formatted.

Comment: @ fmt : I know, I was just using chars as a simple example, in retrospect it was a mistake, since other people also thought I dont know to print strings :).  I did not want to have a vector of strings as a member inside struct since it would be more complicated... mistakes were made :)